# how to solve Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am using jtds 1.2.2 driver with SQL Server 2008. Below is the query I tried to execute

```
SELECT * from AM_API  FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Anyway after executing above query I got below error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2816)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2254)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getMoreResults(TdsCore.java:631)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:477)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:777)
    at org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.db.DatabaseHostObject.executeQuery(DatabaseHostObject.java:510)
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402746/razor-sql-error) that saying FETCH is working on SQL Server 2012 onwards only. Then how to limit result in SQL server 2008. The query going to execute is not under my control. I just postfixed `FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY` to the query to limit the result. So is there a way to limit the result by adding a limit query as a postfix to the query.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Upgrading to SQL Server 2012 will help but you'll still get the same error. From the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx):

> Limitations in Using OFFSET-FETCH:
>
> - ORDER BY is mandatory to use OFFSET and FETCH clause.
> - OFFSET clause is mandatory with FETCH. You can never use, ORDER BY … FETCH.

To return a non-deterministic 10 rows from your table you could do this in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT * 
FROM AM_API
ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

If you cannot upgrade you have a few additional options. [SET ROWCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx) is not deprecated for `SELECT` statements so the following should work on SQL Server 2008:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10;

SELECT * 
FROM AM_API;

SET ROWCOUNT 0;
```

You could also use a TOP expression:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM AM_API;
```